# Using GROUP BY and JOIN-ing non-aggregated columns to query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

I know there are many similar questions, but I haven't managed to solve my problem by reading them. I'd appreciate some pointers.

Here's some example data from my `dummy` table below:

> | id | foo | bar | baz | moo | ins_date | percentage | yes | no | maybe |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 38 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-05-26 06:59:00 | 81 | 25 | 529 | 196 |
> | 41 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-05-29 06:43:00 | 83 | 441 | 144 | 49 |
> | 23 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-06-24 08:48:00 | 62 | 9 | 1 | 16 |
> | 20 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-06-27 10:37:00 | 94 | 676 | 16 | 400 |
> | 65 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-07-01 08:34:00 | 92 | 121 | 64 | 225 |
> | 68 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-07-04 01:46:00 | 91 | 324 | 25 | 289 |
> | 71 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-07-06 23:44:00 | 65 | 196 | 676 | 100 |
> | 74 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-07-10 09:41:00 | 92 | 1024 | 121 | 81 |
> | 77 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-07-13 06:47:00 | 64 | 576 | 169 | 1 |
> | 96 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-08-02 10:34:00 | 78 | 1369 | 256 | 81 |
> | 99 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-08-04 08:25:00 | 82 | 2809 | 9 | 256 |
> | 102 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-08-07 06:49:00 | 87 | 576 | 9 | 676 |
> | 105 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-08-10 03:29:00 | 68 | 4225 | 1089 | 196 |
> | 108 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-08-13 03:59:00 | 92 | 1156 | 169 | 484 |
> | 111 | foothing | bar_one | pizazz | amoosing | 2018-08-16 05:34:00 | 63 | 1764 | 100 | 108 |

I want to achieve the following through a single query:

1. Filter all rows to get an ins_date between a date range that I choose
2. Get the **maximum** ins_date per group of foo, bar, baz and moo
3. Be able to filter rows by foo, bar, baz and moo
4. Additionally show non-grouped values in the query, such as percentage, yes, no and maybe.

Overall this is proving to be complex. So far I've managed to achieve the first 3 points in the query below, and hopefully this explains what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT
  s.foo,
  s.bar, 
  s.baz,
  s.moo,
  MAX(s.ins_date) mdate
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dummy
  WHERE ins_date
  -- My arbitrary date range goes here
  BETWEEN '2018-07-01 00:00:00'
  AND '2019-11-01 23:59:59'
) s

GROUP BY foo, bar, baz, moo
-- I could add other filters into the 'HAVING' clause
HAVING moo LIKE "%moo%"
AND baz = "baz"
```

This gives the output:

> | foo | bar | baz | moo | mdate |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | foothing | bar_one | baz | amoosing | 2018-11-29 05:31:00 |
> | foothing | bar_one | baz | mooman_being | 2019-04-21 10:31:00 |
> | foothing | bar_one | baz | strawberry_moosse | 2019-03-17 06:37:00 |

In this example, if I were to change the date constraint to show only dates between `2018-05-01` and `2018-05-29`, then for the first row `mdate` would show `2018-05-29 06:43:00`, because that's the latest (most recent) date within that date range, for that particular grouping of foo/bar/baz/moo.

But I haven't been able to append the other columns which aren't related to this grouping. I've tried by using a JOIN ...

```
SELECT
  s1.foo,
  s1.bar, 
  s1.baz,
  s1.moo,
  MAX(s1.ins_date) mdate,
  s2.percentage,
  s2.yes,
  s2.maybe,
  s2.no
FROM 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dummy
  WHERE ins_date
  -- My arbitrary date range goes here
  BETWEEN '2018-07-01 00:00:00'
  AND '2019-11-01 23:59:59'
) s1
-- Attempting to a do a self-join to get the non-aggregated columns
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id, percentage, yes, maybe, no
  FROM dummy
) s2
ON s2.id = s1.id

GROUP BY foo, bar, baz, moo
-- I could add other filters into the 'HAVING' clause
HAVING moo LIKE "%moo%"
AND baz = "baz"
```

But this returns the error:

> Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 's2.percentage' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How do I add the non-aggregated columns to my query without breaking it?

I'm using mysql 5.7, so fancy mysql 8 options aren't available.

**Fiddle below:**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1980dd582c2235dc0938cb14c781e3c6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe by aggregating the extra columns?

> ```
> SELECT foo, bar, baz, moo
> , MAX(ins_date) AS mdate
> , AVG(percentage) AS avg_perc
> , MAX(yes) AS YEAHBABY
> , MAX(maybe) AS MAYBEBABY
> , MAX(no) AS NONONONONOOO
> FROM dummy dum
> WHERE ins_date BETWEEN '2018-07-01 00:00:00'
>                    AND '2019-11-01 23:59:59'
>   AND moo LIKE '%moo%'
>   AND baz = 'baz' 
> GROUP BY foo, bar, baz, moo
> ```
>
> ```
> foo      | bar     | baz | moo               | mdate               | avg_perc | YEAHBABY | MAYBEBABY | NONONONONOOO
> :------- | :------ | :-- | :---------------- | :------------------ | -------: | -------: | --------: | -----------:
> foothing | bar_one | baz | amoosing          | 2018-11-29 05:31:00 |  82.8000 |    11236 |       625 |          841
> foothing | bar_one | baz | mooman_being      | 2019-04-21 10:31:00 |  70.0000 |     3969 |        16 |          121
> foothing | bar_one | baz | strawberry_moosse | 2019-03-17 06:37:00 |  80.0000 |    23716 |       529 |           49
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e11dd0bfe2115bf7d1d79850089d8fbd)*

Or join to the grouped fields and MAX date.

Or use an emulated row_number.

Or use an `EXISTS`.

> ```
> SELECT foo, bar, baz, moo
> , ins_date
> , percentage
> , yes, maybe, no
> FROM dummy dum
> WHERE EXISTS (
>   SELECT 1
>   FROM dummy dum2
>   WHERE dum2.ins_date BETWEEN '2018-07-01 00:00:00'
>                           AND '2019-11-01 23:59:59'
>     AND dum2.moo LIKE '%moo%'
>     AND dum2.baz = 'baz'
>     AND dum2.foo = dum.foo
>     AND dum2.bar = dum.bar
>     AND dum2.baz = dum.baz
>     AND dum2.moo = dum.moo
>   GROUP BY foo, bar, baz, moo
>   HAVING MAX(dum2.ins_date) = dum.ins_date
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> foo      | bar     | baz | moo               | ins_date            | percentage |   yes | maybe |  no
> :------- | :------ | :-- | :---------------- | :------------------ | ---------: | ----: | ----: | --:
> foothing | bar_one | baz | strawberry_moosse | 2019-03-17 06:37:00 |         80 | 23716 |   529 |  49
> foothing | bar_one | baz | mooman_being      | 2019-04-21 10:31:00 |         70 |  3969 |    16 | 121
> foothing | bar_one | baz | amoosing          | 2018-11-29 05:31:00 |         97 |  9025 |   361 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=da382bfe455cbc10c44bf4ac28b11c84)*

Comment: That doesn't work for my data unfortunately - I need the exact value for the non-agg columns at the row for the latest ins_date, not an aggregated value. I like your column aliases though.

Comment: @Lou So the 2nd solution is more like it.

Comment: Thank you - I've tested this on my real solution and so far it seems to work!

Comment: Thx. Btw, check out [this article](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/). It's what would be used more in MySql 8.